# In Excel, how do I access the {value in col B} of the same row whose {value in col A} equals the {{value in row x of col A} minus 365}?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

In Excel, how do I access the {value in col B} of the same row whose {value in col A} equals the {{value in row x of col A} minus 365}? My intention is to calculate a vehicle's running average (annual) fuel efficiency of the previous 12 months using the irregularly spaced fuel and mileage logs.

Col A contains ascending dates, with large various gaps in the dates between adjacent cells. Col B contains the corresponding odometer reading, and Col C the corresponding fuel that was purchased on that date.

Starting at least one year after the first entry, I wish to calculate the running annual average value for the miles per gallon and place it in, say, Col D of row x. Row x corresponds to the date that is at least one year after the first entry.

The numerator will be the difference between the contents of cell Bx and the corresponding value residing in the cell of Col B whose row corresponds to the date (with appropriate rounding) in Col A that is earlier by 365 days of the date in row x of Col A.

The denominator will be the sum of the contents of cells from the cell of Col C whose row corresponds to the date (same appropriate rounding as above) in Col A that is earlier by 365 days of the date in row x of Col A to cell Cx.

I wish I could insert a sketch illustrating the 2D layout of the address referencing that is needed. I hope my words this time more clearly describe the situation and will do instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions on what the data may look like, so there may need to be some tweaking depending how irregular your "irregularly spaced" is.

I have assumed there is a header row, so the first time you can have 365 days worth of data is row 366.
I have assumed there is a row for each day, without any gaps. If the days aren't sequential without gaps, the formula takes on a whole new level of ugly to calculate 365 days prior to the current day, and then go search for that date, or closest date after, just to set the top end of the range to do SUMS on.

I have also assumed Col A is the date, Col B is the gallons used that day, and Col C is miles driven that day.  Columns B and C may have gaps, but that shouldn't affect my answer.

In Cell D366, you would have the formula:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(D366,-364,-1,365,1))/SUM(OFFSET(D366,-364,-2,365,1))
```

This will give you the sum of miles from the previous 364 rows(plus that days miles), one column to the left divided by the sum of gallons from the previous 364 rows(plus that days gallons), two columns to the left.